# For loop to delete rows

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm using a macro that lists all of the filenames in whatever directory I choose.  I'm writing code that will break apart the file name into chunks that I can use later.  The list of filenames starts at cell F6 and runs down the column.  Here is the code that I've written so far:

```
Dim ContractNum As String
Dim InvNum As String
Dim FileRng As Range
Dim FileLastRow As Long
Dim File As Range

FileLastRow = Sheet1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set FileRng = Sheet1.Range("F6:F" & FileLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)

For Each File In FileRng
If File = "Invoice.zip" Or File = "Thumbs.db" Then
    File.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next File


For Each File In FileRng
    ContractNum = Left(File, 4)
    InvNum = Mid(File, 8, 6)
    File.Offset(0, -5) = ContractNum
    File.Offset(0, -4) = InvNum
Next File
```

So far I've got that part working fine.  The problem I'm having is that in all of the directories ill use this macro with, there are unwanted files such as "Thumbs.db" or "Invoice.zip".  The code I'm having a problem with is below:

```
For Each File In FileRng
If File = "Invoice.zip" Or File = "Thumbs.db" Then
    File.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next File
```

What I'm wanting this to do is scan through the entire list of filenames and if it encounters a filename of "Thumbs.db" or "Invoice.zip", delete the entire row.  So far, this works...kinda.  For example, if there are two files in my list that are named "Thumbs.db" and "Invoice.zip", I have to run the macro twice to remove both. Obviously, I would like to wipe them all out in one swoop.

Comment: Run a regular for loop backwards `for I = filelastrow to 6 step -1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my comments, change the for loop to this:

```
For i = filelastrow to 6 step -1
   If Sheet1.Cells(i,6) = "Invoice.zip" Or Sheet1.Cells(i,6)  = "Thumbs.db" Then
        Sheet1.row(i).Delete
   End If
Next File
```

The issue is that when  a row gets deleted the one below becomes that row and the loop then skips it as it moves to the next.  It also will then move through empty rows on the end.

By going backwards this problem is eliminated.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott!  after some tinkering this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Great question! @Scott Craner's answer does the trick nicely (upvoted btw), and you wind up with a readable, effective slice of VBA. Good stuff!

There is another way to delete rows quickly that I think deserves a shake: the [`Range.Autofilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) strategy! Check it out, with the Autofilter strategy starting with comments below:

```
Public Sub DeleteRowsWithAutofilter()

    Dim ContractNum As String
    Dim InvNum As String
    Dim FileRng As Range
    Dim FileLastRow As Long
    Dim File As Range
    Dim t As Single
    t = Timer

    FileLastRow = Sheet2.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Identify the total range of filenames, including the header
    Set FileRng = Sheet2.Range("F5:F" & FileLastRow)

    'Use the .Autofilter method to crush those
    'annoying 'Thumbs.db' or 'Invoice.zip' rows
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With FileRng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Thumbs.db", _
                              Operator:=xlOr, _
                              Criteria2:="Invoice.zip"
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Turn off the autofilter safely
    With Sheet2
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If .FilterMode = True Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With

    MsgBox "Damn son! 'Autofilter' strategy completed in " & Timer - t & " seconds."

End Sub
```

I recorded a short screencast that demonstrates both techniques (the `For` loop and the `Range.Autofilter`) here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1U7Ay5voVOE

Hope that helps as you continue to develop your script!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! i'll keep this in mind for future projects.  I laughed hard at the Message Box portion lol.

Comment: I enjoyed the short screencast. Definitely worth watching.